# Once we have signaled a condition variable, will we keep on executing original thread?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, race-condition

I have a problem below.

```
Process A                             Process B
int A = 0;                            int B = 0;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (condition == FALSE)
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
                                    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
                                    condition = TRUE;
                                    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
                                    pthread_mutex_unlock((&mutex)
   A += 10;                         B += 10;
```

My problem is, if process B has other instructions, ex: int B += 10;,

B will execute B += 10 immediately or A will take control otherwise?

It is, whether process B will continue executing or A will be wake up & take control?

For example, will B += 10 precede A += 10 or vise versa?

Answer (score 1):

Every condition variable is associated with a mutex. The mutex must be held when `pthread_cond_wait` is called; `pthread_cond_wait` releases the mutex, waits for the condition to be signalled, and then reacquires the mutext before returning.

You may call `pthread_cond_signal` with the mutex held, or after releasing the mutex. If it is called with the mutex held, no `pthread_cond_wait` can continue until the mutex is released.

The example code in the question does not release the mutex before executing `B += 10;` [Note 1], so that will definitely execute before `A += 10;`. The mutex must at some point be released, of course.

Once the mutex is released, both threads execute in an unspecified order. If your computer has more than one core (quite common these days), they might both be executing at the same time.

---

Note:

1. `int B += 10;` is invalid. You can't declare a variable and increment it in one statement (where would the variable be initialized?)

Answer (score 0):

It is an undefined behaviour. As you haven't synchronized access, you can't be sure which one is the first. Though in real life it depends upon OS implementation of `pthread_cond_signal`, you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: unspecified behaviour. There is no race condition.

Comment: @rici OK, may be 'unspecified' is more appropriate term here, yet anyway it's evil.

Comment: Why is it evil? It's multiprocessing. Trying to guess which thread will be active is unwise, but having two threads perform unrelated computations simultaneously is the essence of multithreading.

Comment: @rici I mean the evil is to rely on the execution order. And simply guessing which one will be the first (if the operations are completely unrelated), is silly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete because process B never unlocks the mutex.

When process A executes `pthread_cond_wait` it atomically unlocks the mutex and waits for the signal from process B. When process B calls `pthread_cond_signal`, process A will attempt to lock the mutex again. Since B never unlocks the mutex, A will be stuck trying to acquire the mutex.

Hence, only the `B += 10` statement will run. The `A += 10` will run if and only if process B unlocks the mutex.